# App Action Test Tools does not work on Android Studio RC or Canary

Tags: android, android-studio, actions-on-google, app-actions

I've tried to use several version of the plugin with Android Studio 3.6 RC3 and Android Studio 4.0 Canary 9. 
The plugin does not open. 
I've found an error in the log files :

```
2020-02-24 17:15:40,455 [ 210135]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getManifest()Lorg/jetbrains/android/dom/manifest/Manifest; 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getManifest()Lorg/jetbrains/android/dom/manifest/Manifest;
    at com.android.aas.util.ProjectUtils.getActionsXmlResourceUrl(ProjectUtils.java:47)
    at com.android.aas.util.ProjectUtils.getActionModule(ProjectUtils.java:86)
    at com.android.aas.ui.ActionSelectionDialog.lambda$readPackageNameSafely$4(ActionSelectionDialog.java:530)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:936)
    at com.android.aas.ui.ActionSelectionDialog.readPackageNameSafely(ActionSelectionDialog.java:528)
    at com.android.aas.ui.ActionSelectionDialog.lambda$getPreviewAndTryToInitializeModel$6(ActionSelectionDialog.java:598)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$1.run(CoreProgressManager.java:225)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:894)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$9(ApplicationImpl.java:552)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-02-24 17:15:40,455 [ 210135]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 3.6 RC 3  Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6186006 
2020-02-24 17:15:40,455 [ 210135]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_212-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2020-02-24 17:15:40,455 [ 210135]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X 
2020-02-24 17:15:40,456 [ 210136]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin to blame: App Actions Test Tool version: 3.1.0 
2020-02-24 17:15:40,456 [ 210136]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: AAS.Test
```

Seems that version [3.1.3](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12322-app-actions-test-tool/update/78669) of the plugin fix this issue but this version is not compatible with 3.6 RC3 or 4.0 Canary 9.

Did someone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. It's is a known issue, and 3.1.4 is being released. Please check out in around two days. Do keep us posted if this issue persists.

Comment: 3.1.4 is available now. You can go ahead and test. Let us know if you run into any issues.

Comment: I'm using 4.0.0 beta and this version of the plugin is not compatible. I might be able to use 3.6 but I need to change my code base...

Comment: When using 3.6 stable, I can open the tools but when I click "Create Preview", I have an error : App Actions Test Tool v3.1.4: Unknown error.

Comment: Please close and restart AS 3.6. It should work after that. We're looking into it. Also, please be aware 4.0 is still not supported. Will work on that one too. No ETA ATM.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I'm assuming you're testing 3.1.5 released today for Android Studio 4.0.

Comment: @Diego, thanks for this tip, restarting AS did the trick